# How to send email notification from Apache Hive query?

Tags: python, email, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have created external hive table and which is loaded from text files. Whenever the table having duplicate records then I have to send an email notification to particular DL. Is it possible to send email from Hive query? if not Can we use python UDF for that?

I have used the below hive query to capture duplicate records

```
insert overwrite table table_dup
select col1,col2, count(1) as cnt from main_table 
group by col1,col2 having cnt > 1;
```

Below Python UDF will be used to throw error message:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
if line:
     raise DuplicateRecError("Duplicate recs found and find details in table_dup")
else:
     continue
```

I am using IBM Tivoli job scheduler not oozie. In that case which would be better to send email either from Hive query or via python UDF?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you running the duplicate check? Is it scheduled somewhere? If you are using Oozie for scheduling, you can send emails from it pretty easily. I'd imagine you can sent an email pretty easily from a UDF too.

Comment: @StephenODonnell - I have updated the question with more details

Comment: It could be worth trying the UDF approach for the email, but I have never done it. I cannot think of any reason why it wouldn't work, especially if you have already proven it raises the exception ok at the moment.